# Discord.js v13 How to prevent the bot from crashing on attempted message deletion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have this 'clear' command for my discord bot and it should work like this:
-user types in !mute

1. the bot deletes this many messages (up to 100)
2. the bot sends a message saying that these messages were deleted
3. the bot deletes that message 5 seconds later
   It all works except for the last part, you see if after executing part 2 the message is deleted by another source then the bot can't find a message to delete and crashes.
   The code is as follow:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: "clears messages",
    async execute(message, args)
    {   
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("Please specify how many messages you want to clear!");
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please enter a number of messages you want to clear!");
        
        if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("You can't delete more than 100 messages!");
        if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("You can't delete less than 1 message!");

        await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then(messages =>{
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(() => {
                message.channel.send("Deleted " + args[0] + " messages") .then(msg => {
                    let id = msg.id;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        if(message.channel.messages.fetch(id))
                        {
                            try {
                                msg.delete()
                            }
                            catch (error) {
                                console.log(error)
                                return
                            }
                        }
                    }, 5000);
                  })
                });
            })
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async MessageManager._fetchId (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:219:18) {
  method: 'get',
  path: '/channels/943105549795471443/messages/946096412922368100',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

As you can see I've tried using the try...catch() but it didn't fix the problem. Any ideas on what to do? Or maybe there is a mistake in my code like a missing import or some other thing like that?

Comment: What does `setTimeout(function(){` do here?

Comment: It deletes the messsage after 5 seconds, it might be hard to see because of the amount of tabs I used, but the setTimeout () is actually fully used if that's what you were confused about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off lets take a look at this code:

```js
try {
    msg.delete();
} catch (error) {
    return console.log(error);
}
```

This code won't do what you expect. `msg.delete();` is a function that returns a `Promise`. A `try/catch` structure won't do anything if the promise fails. So instead, to catch the error, you have to use the catch method on the Promise, just as you used `.then()` earlier, you'll have to use `.catch()`.

So your new code will be like this:

```js
msg.delete().catch(error => console.error(error);
// Or, even better:
msg.delete().catch(console.error);
```

That is the exact same thing here:

```js
if (message.channel.messages.fetch(id))
```

That will always be `true` because the `fetch()` function will return a `Promise` ans since it is neither a `0`, `''` (empty string),`NaN`, `false`, `undefined` or `null` [See here for false values](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/falsy-values-in-javascript/)

Instead, what you're trying to do is check if the messages contain your id:

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch(id).then(msg => {
    // Do what you want with the fetched msg
}).catch(error => {
    // Console error why it failed to fetch the id (probably because it doesn't exist or got deleted)
    message.reply('Failed to fetch the id');
});
```

Lastly this code also has some issues:

```js
message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(() => {
```

`messages` is a `Collection`, not a number, `bulkDelete()` waits for a number so instead do this:

```js
message.channel.bulkDelete(messages.size).then(() => {
```

I personnally don't see why you have to fetch the message, you can simply do this:

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch({
    limit: args[0]
}).then(messages => {
    message.channel.bulkDelete(messages.size).then(() => {
        message.channel.send(`Deleted ${args[0]} messages`).then(msg => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 5000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to `await` `msg.delete()` inside your `try` block. A promise must be settled before it can be tested for any error.

```js
try {
  // Add 'await'
  await msg.delete();
} catch (error) {
  return console.log(error);
}
```

If you want to void the error to have the function fail silently:

```js
msg.delete()
   .catch(() => null);
```

You can also check `Message#deletable` before having your client attempt to delete it:

```js
if (msg.deletable) {
   // I'd still recommend adding your preferred error handling
   msg.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return message.reply({ content: "Done" })
          .then(m => setTimeout(() => message.delete().catch(() => null), 2500))
```

use it like this it'll solve the issue for d.js v13.6